# Need to center align a span inside a div both vertically and horizontally using less(css)

Tags: css

I am using LESS (CSS) trying to align a span (button text) inside a div (button). The span is centrally aligned horizontally but is top aligned vertically. I would also like the span object to adjust itself to the text size automatically.

Here's the LESS code:

```
.button(@color:@crimson-red) {
  border-radius: @small-border-radius;
  border-style: none;
  background-color: @color;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.button-font {
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  color: @off-white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10pt;
  position: relative;
}

.blue-button {
  .button(@blue);
}
```

Comment: can you share html or create fiddle what you have create so far?

Comment: There's no hardcoded html. Its all dynamically generated by JQuery. the .blue-button class is applied to a div and the button-font to a span.

Comment: what the HTML generated by dynamic code, can you share?

Comment: This is not really so much a LESS issue, as a CSS one. But [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div) are many [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245736/center-vertically-the-content-of-a-div) to it on [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246209/center-vertically-the-content-of-a-div-not-by-line-height).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the [flexbox layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

So by adding the following properties and values to the `.button` selector you can center the `span`.

```
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
```

Here is the full less file for reference.

```
@off-white: #fefefe;
@blue: #4286f4;
@small-border-radius: 5px;

.button(@color:@crimson-red) {
  border-radius: @small-border-radius;
  border-style: none;
  background-color: @color;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.button-font {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  color: @off-white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10pt;
  position: relative;
}

.blue-button {
  .button(@blue);
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

This would be the html:

```
<button class="blue-button">
    <span class="button-font">Hello, lots of text here</span>
</button>
```

Here is a link to a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nicholaschris/zshfzto0/) with compiled css.